# Show just a part of a webpage

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I am developing a C# windows application in which I use a `WebBrowser` control to display a web page. I would like to control the visible area of the `WebBrowser` to display only a particular region of that web page.

The webpage looks like this:
http://weheartimages.com/

... and I'd like to display just the image upload form in my application:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVGv6.png

This (web)form is contained within a div with a particular class; can I restrict the visible region of my `WebBrowser` to that div?

Comment: When you say a "C# Windows Application", do you mean a Windows Forms application, or a WPF application?

Answer (score 2):

Appending this to the page should do it:

```
<style>
    header, .advert, .b-searches, #main-content, footer 
        { display: none!important }
    .inner 
        { width: auto!important }
    #sidebar 
        { margin-left: 0!important }
</style>
```

It basically hides all page elements but the panel you want. Also change the width of the container so the panel is aligned to the top left of the page.

To append the code use this ([source](http://starikovs.com/2009/11/25/set-html-webbrowser-csharp/)):

```
webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true); // Reset to new document
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://weheartimages.com/");
while (webBrowser1.Document == null && webBrowser1.Document.Body == null)
    Application.DoEvents();
webBrowser1.Document.Write(css);
```

Comment: Avoid [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) loops like this, it's a popular anti-pattern. As well, avoid using `Application.DoEvents` unless absolutely necessary. It's almost always possible to use events instead (e.g. `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted`). `Async/await` can be used to simulate linear code flow when using events.

Comment: I will try your method.